# Why does my terrain warp when I unwrap?

Tags: uv

I used many areas of Google terrain from Sketch Up and joined them together in Cycles.  then I stitched them together and removed doubles.  As you can see, when I unwrap it's warped.  I'm a newbee, be gentle :-) [image: 90 degrees clockwise and warped]

Comment: Btw. Where (geographically) is this (the terrain) from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to top view, then in edit mode select all the mesh, hit <kbd>U</kbd> button to unwrap and from the menu select **Project from View (Bounds)**